# How to split the text into two columns that both have a different width?

Tags: two-column, columns, layout

I'm making a report about some code that I've written. I want to split the page into two columns, in such a way that I have code on the left side and (commentary, descriptive, **non-code**) text on right side.

I **do not** want to have this layout throughout the whole document.

I would also like to have a vertical line that 
separates these two columns.

The important part for me is that I want the code column to occupy a lot more space than the text column. The code-columnwidth should be twice as much as the text-columnwith for example.

I have searched the internet for a long time but I couldn't find a suitable solution.

I have tried the following:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
 text..
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

But it can't seem to find a way to specify two different columnwidths for each column. What also bothers me is that I cannot indicate precisely what text goes into what column, it just splits it automatically when the bottom of the page is reached, meaning that I sometimes get code on the right column.

Could anyone help me with this problem? I truly am desperate for any kind of solution. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paracol) package?

Comment: Take a look at the ‘tcolorbox‘ package

Comment: Package `paracol` can take care of that.

Comment: Would it be possible to mock up an example of what you're looking for? For example, it should show how the two columns interact with one another. Do you have long pieces of text that should push the code (on the left) down? Should the text be centred vertically with respect to the code or at the top of the code line it describes? Do you need word wrapping for the text? What package are you using to write the code?

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts! The paracol package has exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

A simple `minipage` solution might be more suitable in your case if you don't require page breaks (you didn't mention this as a requirement in your question), otherwise you can have a look at the `paracol` package mentioned by Mico in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]\clearpage

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\lipsum*[1-2]
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\vrule
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{minipage}

\clearpage
\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

This way you can put whatever you like in the left column (code, in your case), and the descriptive text on the right.

Comment: +1. :-) To assure that the vertical rule is centered between the `minipage` environments, it's important to write `\end{minipage}%` rather than just `\end{minipage}`. The `%` (comment) symbol serves to suppress the whitespace that otherwise gets inserted (as is visible in the screenshot you posted).

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the comment, I'll correct it.

Comment: I decided on the paracol package as it is simpler in my opinion and provides exactly everything I was looking for and more (including synchronized columns, etc.) Nevertheless, thank you so much for your efforts!